# Creating an arrow pointer underneath an equation

Tags: arrows

Is there an option of drawing a curved arrow below an expression that points to its beginning? Looking for something like this:

[image: Cyclic permutation of order 3 visualized]

For representing the action of the cyclic permutation (1 2 3) in some nice visual way, without having to repeat the 1.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome! With `tikz-cd` this is very easy.

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small] 1\arrow[r] & 2 \arrow[r] & 3\arrow[ll,bend left]
\end{tikzcd}\]

You can control all aspects, e.g.\
\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=small] 1\arrow[r] & 2 \arrow[r] & 3
\arrow[ll,bend left=20,start anchor=-120,end anchor=-60]
\end{tikzcd}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 an upvote for the proper explanation of how to handle it....

Answer (score 5):

This is also possible by using `xymatrix`, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix @-2pc{
1 &\to &2 &\to &3
\ar@/^/[llll]
}
\]

\end{document}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]